# Algorithm to determine someones age given only a drivers license number?

Tags: algorithm

I have been debating doing some work on a site which might be age restricted, one of the things have thought about is a hassle free way to confirm a user's age. I recently heard that the site with the movie trailer for the film ted asks people to enter their name and drivers license number to confirm their age. http://www.tedisreal.com/ Are they using an algorithm or is there an open governmental api for this kind of data? I have done some searching on this topic and all I can find is a program written in perl from 2004 which no longer appears to be supported.

Any knowledge about this topic would be appreciated!

Comment: It feels as if this would differ between different countries. My drivers licence number is simply my [personal identity number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_(Sweden)), which starts with my birth date. It should be easy enough to calculate age from that and also verify that the control digit at the end is correct. But yeah, if you want a rigourous check you'd probably have to check towards some national register. Point is that you should probably specify which country you want your service to work for, as solutions might be different for different countries.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that not everyone has a driver's licence.

Comment: I should have specified that I am in the United States, also I know that my state encodes the age into the drivers license number, and state id number but the coding is very odd. Furthermore I know that that coding is not standard among the states in the U.S. However, I was wondering/hoping that perhaps there was a solution that I had not been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms in most US states are confidential. Each state has their own form of algorithms and translations. If you work for a vendor that involves decrypting driver's license information you can request for the documentation from the state's department of licensing.